# Confusing Android Activity lifecycle bahavior

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I did a simple program by overriding each of the lifecycle methods and everything works as I'd expect, except for `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

I overrode the method as

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);   
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onRestoreInstanceState - Activity1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

But it never gets called.

I overrode `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` too and I can see the system calling it, but never the `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. When I press back button or so, I can see that the system calls `onRestore()`, `OnStart()` and `onResume()`, and the UI (just two buttons) are displayed correctly.

How is it possible that the UI is restored without calling `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`? I only do `setContentView(R.layout.main)` is `onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. So how does it restore the UI without calling either `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`?

Would really appreciate somebody shedding some light on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here is a bit confusing, but I think this method is only intended as a kind of stand-in for onCreate's handling of stored state, occurring later in the cycle. It's only called if the activity is destroyed and re-created with state; this would most commonly happen during an orientation change. It's not intended to handle state during ordinary transitions between activities.

See also [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)