# onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()

Tags: android, android-activity, states

I'm trying to save and restore the state of an `Activity` using the methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

The problem is that it never enters the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method. Can anyone explain to me why this is?

Answer (score 196):

Usually you restore your state in `onCreate()`. It is possible to restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()` as well, but not very common. (`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called after `onStart()`, whereas `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`.

Use the put methods to store values in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putLong("param", value);
}
```

And restore the values in `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  if (icicle != null){
    value = icicle.getLong("param");
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I use startActivity to return to activity A. When returning to activity B, the object is null icicle.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what you are doing: From B you call startActivity(A). Then from A you call finish() to get back to B. Right? In that case Your first activity, B will not have been destroyed, and neither onCreate() nor onRestoreInstanceState() will be called. These methods are only called when needed, that is when an activity has been destroyed and needs to be recreated by the system.

Comment: I should add that your first activity, B, might get destroyed due to low memory conditions. This will trigger the onCreate and onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: @Robert does that mean, the state of B should still be available after A?

Comment: erikb, yes, activity B will be resumed, or in case the OS has reclaimed it, recreated and then resumed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Very helpful. I do have one question though. If `onRestoreInstanceState` doesn't need to be used, when should we be using it?

Comment: Since the default onRestoreInstanceState restores all views that can be restored, one might want to override it if there is one particular view that for some weird reason shouldn't be restored.

Comment: Just a correction: "super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);" shoud come first before any NVP entries, else they get destroyed/not saved

Comment: Indeed. Silly me. Thank you, Nitin Bansal. I have corrected the code.

Comment: thanks for the post but this has me confused I hope it is just a typo but should this line super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); read this super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);

Comment: Oops, yet another typo. You are absolutely right, Gurnard. I have corrected the code.

Comment: Just curious ... why is the 'Bundle' variable name "icicle"?

Comment: [Oh, this is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919153/what-is-androids-icicle-parameter)

Comment: Actually android docs, says super() should come last, after any entries. Does it matter?

Comment: JohnyTex, the android source contains many implementations where super() is called first, so I would say that it doesn't matter. But if the documentation says that super() should be called last, it would be prudent to do so.

Answer (score 156):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called **only when recreating** activity after it was **killed** by the OS. Such situation happen when:

- orientation of the device changes (your activity is destroyed and recreated).
- there is another activity in front of yours and at some point the OS kills your activity in order to free memory (for example). Next time when you start your activity onRestoreInstanceState() will be called.

In contrast: if you are in your activity and you hit `Back` button on the device, your activity is finish()ed (i.e. think of it as exiting desktop application) and next time you start your app it is started "fresh", i.e. without saved state because you intentionally exited it when you hit `Back`.

Other source of confusion is that when an app loses focus to another app `onSaveInstanceState()` is called but when you navigate back to your app `onRestoreInstanceState()` may not be called. This is the case described in the original question, i.e. if your activity was NOT killed during the period when other activity was in front `onRestoreInstanceState()` will NOT be called because your activity is pretty much "alive".

All in all, as stated in the documentation for `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

> Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their
>   state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the
>   initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether
>   to use your default implementation. The default implementation of this
>   method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been
>   frozen by onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

As I read it: There is no reason to override `onRestoreInstanceState()` unless you are subclassing `Activity` and it is expected that someone will subclass your subclass.

Comment: yeh this seems to be right, but it sucks. imo it should be also run when returning to the activity from another activity. there are plenty of situations where you need this.

Comment: @masi there are already other methods invoked on Activity when the user returns to it( from another activity). The onSave/RestoreInstanceState() is used for another specific purpose, that's it.

Answer (score 8):

The state you save at `onSaveInstanceState()` is later available at `onCreate()` method invocation. So use `onCreate` (and its `Bundle` parameter) to restore state of your activity.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation [Restore activity UI state using saved instance state](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state) it is stated as:

> Instead of restoring the state during onCreate() you may choose to
> implement onRestoreInstanceState(), which the system calls after the
> onStart() method. The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if
> there is a saved state to restore, **so you do not need to check whether**
> **the Bundle is null**:

[image]

[image]

IMO, this is more clear way than checking this at onCreate, and better fits with single responsiblity principle.

Answer (score 4):

The main thing is that if you don't store in `onSaveInstanceState()` then `onRestoreInstanceState()` will not be called. This is the main difference between `restoreInstanceState()` and `onCreate()`. Make sure you really store something. Most likely this is your problem.

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState() will be called ,even if you dont store anything in OnSaveInstanceState()

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you could store a bundle with the data you want to maintain in the Intent you use to start activity A.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle", theBundledData);
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity A would have to pass this back to Activity B. You would retrieve the intent in Activity B's onCreate method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle intentBundle;
if (intent != null)
    intentBundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
// Do something with the data.
```

Another idea is to create a repository class to store activity state and have each of your activities reference that class (possible using a singleton structure.)  Though, doing so is probably more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 3):

I found that onSaveInstanceState is always called when another Activity comes to the foreground. And so is onStop.

However, onRestoreInstanceState was called only when onCreate and onStart were also called. And, onCreate and onStart were NOT always called.

So it seems like Android doesn't always delete the state information even if the Activity moves to the background. However, it calls the lifecycle methods to save state just to be safe. Thus, if the state is not deleted, then Android doesn't call the lifecycle methods to restore state as they are not needed.

[Figure 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) describes this.

Answer (score 2):

I think this thread was quite old. I just mention another case, that `onSaveInstanceState()` will also be called, is when you call `Activity.moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRootActivity)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling activity's orientation changes with `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` and `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`, `onRestoreInstanceState()` will not be called.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary that onRestoreInstanceState will always be called after onSaveInstanceState.

Note that :
onRestoreInstanceState will always be called, when activity is rotated (when orientation is not handled) or open your activity and then open other apps so that your activity instance is cleared from memory by OS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `onRestoreInstanceState` was called when the activity was reconstructed after changing the device orientation. `onCreate(Bundle)` was called first, but the bundle didn't have the key/values I set with `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Right after, `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` was called with a bundle that had the correct key/values.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and was noticing that the documentation had my answer:

"This function will never be called with a null state."

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Parcelable)

In my case, I was wondering why the onRestoreInstanceState wasn't being called on initial instantiation.  This also means that if you don't store anything, it'll not be called when you go to reconstruct your view.

Answer (score 0):

I can do like that (sorry it's c# not java but it's not a problem...) :

```cs
private int iValue = 1234567890;

function void MyTest()
{
    Intent oIntent = new Intent (this, typeof(Camera2Activity));
    Bundle oBundle = new Bundle();
    oBundle.PutInt("MYVALUE", iValue); //=> 1234567890
    oIntent.PutExtras (oBundle);
    iRequestCode = 1111;
    StartActivityForResult (oIntent, 1111);
}
```

AND IN YOUR ACTIVITY FOR RESULT

```cs
private int iValue = 0;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    Bundle oBundle =  Intent.Extras;
    if (oBundle != null)
    {
        iValue = oBundle.GetInt("MYVALUE", 0);
        //=>1234567890
    }
}

private void FinishActivity(bool bResult)
{
    Intent oIntent = new Intent();
    Bundle oBundle = new Bundle();
    oBundle.PutInt("MYVALUE", iValue);//=>1234567890
    oIntent.PutExtras(oBundle);
    if (bResult)
        {
            SetResult (Result.Ok, oIntent);
        }
    else
        SetResult(Result.Canceled, oIntent);
    GC.Collect();
    Finish();
}
```

FINALLY

```cs
protected override void OnActivityResult(int iRequestCode, Android.App.Result oResultCode, Intent oIntent)
{
    base.OnActivityResult (iRequestCode, oResultCode, oIntent);
    iValue = oIntent.Extras.GetInt("MYVALUE", -1); //=> 1234567890
}
```