# android: application crashes if orientation changes in a subactivity

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

My main activity handles changes into portrait mode just fine.  However, if I launch a very simple activity via `startActivityForResult()` and switch to portrait mode before finishing it, my main activity crashes because some of its variables are set to null.

It looks like my connection to the Service is not being recreated. I tried manually calling `doUnbindService(); doBindService();` inside of `onActivityResult()` but `onServiceConnected()` is still not being called.

What's the proper way to handle the Activity lifecycle here?

*EDIT*: I see in the log file that `onServiceConnected()` is indeed being called -- but it's being called *after* `onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was referring to objects which don't exist until onCreate() is called again. I needed to queue my answers locally and wait for those objects to be recreated to avoid crashes.

Answer (score 2):

For you second Activity add this

```
  if your android:targetSdkVersion="12" or less
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

      if your  android:targetSdkVersion="13" or more
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

in manifest.xml

Comment: The IDE complains about "screenSize" despite my targetSdkVersion being 15.     `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`

Comment: Okay, I forced myself up to the higher API (hopefully it will still work with my older phone) and this doesn't seem to have an effect.
This seems like a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758621/life-cycle-predicament-with-orientation-change-in-another-activity
I might just need to delay handling the result.