# It is possible to avoid the call to onCreate when you changue from landscape to portrait?

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

It is possible to avoid the call to onCreate when you changue from landscape to portrait?

How?

thanks

Comment: No downvote. As I know, it can't be avoided. BTW, what are you trying to do..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely possible, in `AndroidManifest.xml` add this to activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

you can read more information about this tip on my article: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/the-less-known-over-screen-orientation/

Comment: i tryed adding that but it makes my app to give me exception

Comment: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity App did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()

Answer (score 2):

Read this article [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). Basically there are two options

1. Let android handle configuration changes - then your activity will be recreated and `onCreate` will be invoked again.
2. Handle it yourself - then your activity won't be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do this, by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest.

However, by choosing this path, you lose much of the great resource management in Android.

If you want to appropriately save and restore state since the activity is recreated without the above manifest change, then you will want to look at [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Comment: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity App did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()

Answer (score 0):

add this to manifest of the activity -
android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity App did not call through to super.onConfigurationChanged()