# Android - Strange "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Hi I'm trying to make an app in which there's a search box, I've written some code but, when I try to type the first letter in the AutoCompleteTextView, it gives me an error (java.lang.NullPointerException) without any kind of cause about what caused it.

My mains.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<AutoCompleteTextView
 android:id="@+id/acTV"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Scrivi">
<requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:fadingEdge="none" 
 android:fastScrollEnabled="true">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My listitem_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/textView1"
 android:text="TextView"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TextView>
<TextView
 android:text="TextView"
 android:id="@+id/textView2"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My code:

```
public class Search extends Activity {
    AutoCompleteTextView acTV;
    ListView lview;

    String[] first = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

    String[] second = {"Uno", "Due", "Tre", "Quattro", "Cinque", "Sei", "Sette", "Otto", "Nove", "Dieci"};
    int textlength = 0;
    ArrayList<String> first_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> second_sort = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mains);

        acTV = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acTV);
        lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(first, second));

        lview.setClickable(true);
        lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Search.this, Details.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            {
            }
        });

        lview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        acTV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {

                textlength = acTV.getText().length();
                first_sort.clear();
                second_sort.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= first[i].length()) {
                        if (acTV.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) first[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {
                            first_sort.add(first[i]);
                            second_sort.add(first[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                lview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(first_sort, second_sort));

            }
        });
    }

    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] data_first;
        String[] data_second;

        {

        }

        MyCustomAdapter(String[] first, String[] second) {
            data_first = first;
            data_second = second;
        }

        MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> first, ArrayList<String> second) {
            for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
                data_first[i] = first.get(i);
                data_second[i] = second.get(i);
            }

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data_first.length;
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, parent, false);

            TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            textview.setText(data_first[position]);
            textview1.setText(data_second[position]);

                return (row);

           }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error I receive when I try to type a letter:

12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at     it.gogle.com.Search$MyCustomAdapter.(Search.java:114)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at     it.gogle.com.Search$2.onTextChanged(Search.java:87)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at     android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6240)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6281)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6456)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-24 01:37:55.231: E/AndroidRuntime(15241):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks to every person who helps me.

Comment: What line of code is `Search.java` line 114?

Comment: data_first[i] = first.get(i);

Comment: That's all my code, it's not divided in two activities, it's all in one. I don't see any error about it's not properly formatted at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that one of the `sort` parameters is `null`.

Confirmed by OP comment, `first_sort` is `null`.

---

As per [this blog post](http://rschilling.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/android-activity-lifecycle-and-instance-management/), you need to:

1. Save the values of all your class variables, including static variables in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to the bundle.
2. Restore the variables from the bundle (if it’s not `null`) in `onCreate(Bundle)`.

See also:

- [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)
- [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

---

...something like this (**not tested**):

```
public class Search extends Activity {
    // snip...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // snip...

        if (first_sort == null) {
            first_sort = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("first_sort");
        }

        if (second_sort == null) {
            second_sort = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("second_sort");
        }
    }

    // snip...

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("first_sort", first_sort);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("second_sort", second_sort);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is my first application and I'm not as good as maybe you can imagine. Could you help me writing the missing code or giving a better clue? Thank you again.
P.S. I use android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" in Manifest instead of onSave and onRestore. It works also fine.
Thanks also for the other help.

Comment: When I said if you could help me writing code I meant about how to resolve NullPointerException, if you could.

Comment: I've modified this example code [link](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/07/android-search-in-custom-listview.html?showComment=1324684325255#c535218314476375289) for my needs, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work. I have two String[] instead of a String[] and an int[] as in the example. Maybe is this what causes the error?