# Saving and restoring an activity's state - Bundle always null?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, oncreate

I know this question is asked everywhere, and I have tried looking at answers such as this one: [onSaveInstanceState not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813142/onsaveinstancestate-not-working) as it is similar to mine however I can't find a solution.

This is my code:

```
public class SelectCamera extends AppCompatActivity {
static final String LIST_SAVE = "CAM-LIST";
String testString = "";
String testString02 = "please work";
private static final String TAG = "SELECTCAMERA ";
IPCamera ic = new IPCamera("Demo cam", "http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&amp%3bdummy=1333689998337", "admin1", "password", this);
IPCamera testc = new IPCamera("TEST", "test.com", "admin1", "password", this);
static ArrayList<IPCamera> listOfCameras = new ArrayList<IPCamera>(); //Arrays.asList(ic)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        System.out.println("WHAT IS SAVED: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println("NOTHING IS HERE ATM");
    }
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        System.out.println("THERE IS A SAVE --------------------");
        //listOfCameras.clear();
        listOfCameras = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(LIST_SAVE);
        testString = savedInstanceState.getString("test");
    } else {
        System.out.println("I am an IDIOT.....");
        listOfCameras.add(ic);
        listOfCameras.add(testc);
    }

    System.out.println("DOES THIS WORK: " + testString);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_camera);

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cameraList);

    camListAdapter adapter = new camListAdapter(this, listOfCameras);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            IPCamera listItem = (IPCamera) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera \"" + listItem.name + "\" selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            ConnectCamera.title = listItem.name;

            IPCamera cameraData = listItem;
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConnectCamera.class);
            i.putExtra("selectedCamera", cameraData);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving state.......");
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(LIST_SAVE, listOfCameras);
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("Camlist", listOfCameras);
    savedInstanceState.putString("test", testString02);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println(savedInstanceState.toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "RESTORING......");
    System.out.println(savedInstanceState.toString());
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    listOfCameras = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(LIST_SAVE);
    testString = savedInstanceState.getString("test");
}
}

class camListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<IPCamera> {
public camListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<IPCamera> cams) {
    super(context, 0, cams);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    IPCamera camera = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.select_camera_item, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.camName);
    TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.camURL);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(camera.name);
    tvHome.setText(camera.url);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
}
```

As you can see I have a lot of print statements to try and work out what's going wrong and why. No matter how I destroy the activity or if I move onto another activity, the Bundle will get saved and I know this because when I print the Bundle as the activity is destroyed it prints out correctly, but then when I return to the activity the Bundle is always null. Any help?

Comment: Bundle used in onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState is not for saving  the data persistent ... it is more for (with great simplification) storing data between activities backstack or orientation change ...

Comment: @Selvin how would I go about saving the data persistent? As this is what I would like to achieve

Answer (score 0):

try to call `super.onSaveInstanceState` at the end of that method (last line), and `super.onRestoreInstanceState` at the beginning (first line)

Comment: It shouldn't matter when the super method is called, the onCreate would still do the correct thing

Comment: I have tried this and it just causes the application to crash