# Activity clears all its data if a incoming call is recieved?

Tags: android, phone-call

I have developed an application (somewhat a maths quiz) In which user chooses answers in 4-5 options and there are around 10 questions. While answering the questions if device recieves an incoming call ,the activity gets cleared up and all the answers ticked by the user are cleared. I am updating the table each time user answer a question.This activity is a complex one .

How can I save the state of the application and restart from the same point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **saveInstanceState** and **restoreInstanceState**, to hold your data refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101501/1173391), to see how to use this.

Comment: what means a lot of data to store, you can also implement a custom class for your data you want to store,... that is the Android lifecycle there is no way to bypass it.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html#Pause

You can save instance state on pause and restore it on resume