# how can I value pass between 2 activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I'm trying to write an app like a memo.
First here is a listView in the A_activity.
And I have second activity named B_activity to do the memo.
I put a button in the A_activity and use it to Add a memo.
So, I use intent to switch A_activity to B_activity.

Now here is the problem:
I use the same way to switch B_activity back to A_activity with a bundle stored the values.
I want the result is the listView would add a memo I just create and the old memo will remain.
But all failed.
I know how to do but dont know how to write the code. 
Can someone give me some example?

Comment: please formulate clearer what you want to achieve. I think you are misunderstood by most people reading your question because of the misleading title.

Comment: im sorry , im not good at English. I know, but I want to try write something like memolist. A list of memos in A and if I want to add or modify the memo I click the button to B to change or add the value. And back to A when I finished. this is all I want to do.

Comment: and...what's the problem exactly if you just want to switch the activities? finish the first and start the second and the other way round. Maybe someone can help you if you post some code.

Comment: ok. i will update when I back to the office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understand, you send `Intent` from A to B and after some logic send `Intent` from B to A, and do it many times. If I am rigth it is very awful method. Your activity's stack will be populated and back button will work not correct. I think you should use `startActivtyForResult()` from A and `setResult()` in B. I hope I am right. In this way you can pass `Bundle` from A to Intent and return `Bundle` to `onResult()`;

Good luck!

Comment: I know, but I want to try write something like memolist. A list of  memos in A and if I want to add or modify the memo I click the button to B to change or add the value. And back to A when I finished.

Comment: Is anything can do this ?

Comment: Ok I see. And where is problem?)

Comment: The last step back to A with some value failed. the memolist clean all the old memo.

Comment: in the onCreate of your first activity, try the answer from @Hisham Muneer. If you do it right this will work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate check this topic. Its for your problem. You should save your data in onSaveInstanteState and restore it in onCreate or onRestoreInstanteState().

Answer (score 3):

In your A activity before passing data to listView check if bundle is null.

ex -

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null)
{
    // pass your values to listview
} else {
    return;
}
```

Instead use startActivityForResult(); method for these kind of operations.