# how can I prevent activity label from changing when rotating

Tags: android, android-activity

I use `setTitle` to change the activity label on runtime. But every time when rotating the phone, the activity label changes back to its initial state. How can I prevent this?

Comment: when the orientation changes your activity restarts in usual case.. do you wanto prevent it from restarting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the following in your activity declaration in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

It will prevent your activity to be restarted when orientation is changed.

EDIT:

From this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/456918/931982) it suggested to use the following for newer api

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: `<activity
            android:name="com.example.deck.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >` I've already added it. It seems that it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can save and restore your state of Activity using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Preventing orientation change is also a good method, but i'd like to recommend to use these functions for more flexibility to your application.

For more information, you can see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)