# android restore state of edittext after returning to the activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, state, retain

I am beginner to android developing and I am dealing with a probably simply solvable problem.
I have a Main activity which is a menu and the user can click on of the items on menu. Then a new Activity is started using startActivity(new Intent("com.example.test.FIRSTITEM")); this activity starts a layout with few edittexts. I write something into them. Then to go back to the MainActivity (where the menu is) one have to press back button. 
**And now I want the behaviour that if I return to the Activity with edittexts, I want them to be in the same state - meaning the content wouldn't be cleared.**
I've searched a lot and tried all options of android:launchMode="" (singleTop, singleInstance, singleTask).
I've also tried to use flags when starting new intent from MainActivity:
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.test.FIRSTITEM").setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP))
I've tried using onSavedInstanceState(Bundle bundle) but this one is never called when pressing back button (probably because the activity isn't really finished)

I am sure the answer is simple but I can't seem to find it. I must be missing some logic of how activities work.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: you need to store the data from editext somewhere when you return to the activity retrieve the data and set the data to editext.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: so is the shared preferences option the only one that will work? I thought this is mainly used for saving the data after the app is closed completely. I thought there will be an easier way to do it if I don't need to keep the data after stopping the app.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html check the link for other storage options. Use the one that your app requires

Comment: The Shared preferences seems to be the most suitable option for my app. Now it is working as expected. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate) this could help you out.You can use
`onsaveinstancestate()` and  `onrestoreinstancestate()`.

Comment: I've actually tried this but these are never called, when I need them to. I've already solved the issue by using shared preferences. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sharedpreference is not right way. It consumes more resources.