# Is onRestoreInstanceState() called only in case of screen rotation?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have a question regarding Activity Lifecycle in Android.
I want to know, in what situation the method onRestoreInstanceState() is called ?

The documentation says

> "The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved
>   state to restore"

But I want to know when can this situation occur. Is it only applicable in case of screen rotation, when the foreground activity is destroyed and recreated ?

Answer (score 5):

From the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate):

`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called **only when recreating** activity after it was **killed** by the OS. Such situation happen when:

- orientation of the device changes (your activity is destroyed and recreated)
- there is another activity in front of yours and at some point the OS kills your activity in order to free memory (for example). Next time when you start your activity `onRestoreInstanceState()` will be called.

In contrast: if you are in your activity and you hit `Back` button on the device, your activity is finish()ed (i.e. think of it as exiting desktop application) and next time you start your app it is started "fresh", i.e. without saved state because you intentionally exited it when you hit `Back`.

Other source of confusion is that when an app loses focus to another app `onSaveInstanceState()` is called but when you navigate back to your app `onRestoreInstanceState()` may not be called. This is the case described in the original question, i.e. if your activity was NOT killed during the period when other activity was in front `onRestoreInstanceState()` will NOT be called because your activity is pretty much "alive".

All in all, as stated in the documentation for `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

> Most implementations will simply use onCreate(Bundle) to restore their
>   state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the
>   initialization has been done or to allow subclasses to decide whether
>   to use your default implementation. The default implementation of this
>   method performs a restore of any view state that had previously been
>   frozen by onSaveInstanceState(Bundle).

As I read it: There is no reason to override `onRestoreInstanceState()` unless you are subclassing `Activity` and it is expected that someone will subclass your subclass.

Not only that, but also:

Usually you restore your state in `onCreate()`. It is possible to restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()` as well, but not very common. (`onRestoreInstanceState()` is called after `onStart()`, whereas `onCreate()` is called before `onStart()`.

Use the put methods to store values in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle icicle) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(icicle);
  icicle.putLong("param", value);
}
```

And restore the values in `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
  if (icicle != null){
    value = icicle.getLong("param");
  }
}
```

You do not have to store view states, as they are stored automatically.