# Use a checkbox to allow the user to save the values in the textviews and editview so they are seen immedietly upon reopening the application.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sharedpreferences, savestate

Very new to android java programming. I created a car payment calculator application for one of my classes and I am trying to create a checkbox that the user can check so that all the values stored in the TextViews and EditViews remain the same when the application is opened again.

Here is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnEditorActionListener, OnItemSelectedListener, OnFocusChangeListener,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {
private TextView payment;
private TextView interest;
private EditText principle;
private TextView interestText;
private CheckBox interestBox;
private EditText years;
private TextView apr;
Button plusbutton;
Button minusbutton;
private static String TAG = "CAR";
private Spinner period;
private double aprPercent;
private int t;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    this.getReferences();
    this.setListeners();    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void getReferences() {
    payment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paymentLabel);
    interest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.interestLabel);
    apr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aprLabel);
    aprPercent = Double.parseDouble(apr.getText().toString());
    interestText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.interestText);
    interestBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    interestBox.setChecked(false);
    principle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.principleEditText);
    years = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yearsEditText);
    period = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    minusbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minusbutton);
    plusbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.split_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    period.setAdapter(adapter);


    // principle.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    Log.d(TAG, "getReferences principle: " + principle.getText()
            + " years:" + years.getText());

}

public void setListeners() { // where the event being consumed will be
                                // responding
    principle.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    principle.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    years.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    years.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
    interestBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    period.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "setListeners principle: " + principle.getText() + " years:"
            + years.getText());
}

public void setPeriodValue() {
    if (period.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Monthly")) {
        t = 12;
    } else if (period.getSelectedItem().toString()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Quarterly")) {
        t = 4;
    } else if (period.getSelectedItem().toString()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Annually")) {
        t = 1;
    }
}

public void updateResults() {
    double dblPrinciple = Double
            .parseDouble(principle.getText().toString());
    double dblYears = Double.parseDouble(years.getText().toString());

    double num, denom, dblPayment;
    double r = aprPercent / 100;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    NumberFormat curr = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    apr.setText(nf.format(aprPercent));
    setPeriodValue();
    num = (r / t);
    denom = (1 - Math.pow((1 + num), (t * -dblYears)));
    dblPayment = dblPrinciple * (num / denom);
    payment.setText(curr.format(dblPayment));
    interest.setText(curr
            .format((dblPayment * t * dblYears) - dblPrinciple));

}

public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasfocus) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Focus Change principle: " + principle.getText() + " years"
            + years.getText());
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.principleEditText:
    case R.id.yearsEditText:
        updateResults();
    default:
        updateResults();

    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(interestBox.isChecked()) {
        interest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        interestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        interest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        interestText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    if (interestBox.isChecked()!=true){
        interest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        interestText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        interest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        interestText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }       
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    updateResults();
}

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    updateResults();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.minusbutton:
        if (aprPercent == 1) {
            break;
        } else {
            aprPercent = aprPercent - 1.0;
            updateResults();
            break;
        }
    case R.id.plusbutton:
        if (aprPercent == 20) {
            break;
        } else {
            aprPercent = aprPercent + 1.0;
            updateResults();
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    updateResults();
}
```

My guess is that I have to do something with sharedprefs but I'm not exactly sure how to go about it. Any push in the right direction would be great. thank you.

Comment: did you tried one of the solutions below?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getSharedPreferences(...).edit().putString(...).commit()` to store values in "onPause()" and again use `getSharedPreferences(...).getString(...)` to retrieve information in your "onResume()". It's just that easy.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read how to save your [**Activity data**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState). In my opinion you should not use checkbox to save this data but save it by default.

To save your data while the screen rotate you will have to check the `OnSaveInstanceState` and `OnRestoreInstanceState` like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate). It will handle the data when rotated too.

To save your data for a longer time (changing of applications, closing application), You will have to use the Android preferences but check how works the [lifecycle of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). Basically you will need to save in the `OnPause` or `OnDestroy` and reload it in the `OnResume` or `OnCreate`.

Concerning the preferences you have a nice tutorial on the [Vogella Website](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

```
//Get Data
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String url = settings.getString("url", "n/a"); 

//Save Data
Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString("username", "new_value_for_user");
edit.apply();
```