# ArrayList<Custom Object> saveInstanceState not returning list

Tags: java, android, arraylist, savestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I have an `ArrayList<>` of a custom `Object` that I need to save when my users close down my app. I can see in logcat that it "saves" it to `outBundle` when I use `Bundle.putParcelableArrayList`, but it doesn't recover it when I start the app again, either with Genymotion or physical phone. I also can't cast the `final String` to `Serializable` for whatever reason if that would help.

```
static final String tasks = "tasks";

outState.putParcelableArrayList(tasks, taskList); //this works

taskList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(tasks); //this doesn't
```

I've tried calling it in `onCreate` with a `(savedInstanceState != null)` statement and in `onRestoreInstanceState`.
Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT:** this is what I want to see in logCat:

```
outState.putParcelableArrayList(tasks, taskList);
        System.out.println("saved: " + taskList);
```

And this is what I get:

```
04-15 09:24:27.513    1791-1791/com.aau.uni.mea2015.a317b.cueless I/System.out﹕ saved: [this is a task
04-15 09:24:27.513    1791-1791/com.aau.uni.mea2015.a317b.cueless I/System.out﹕ 0 - 1 minutter, 1 underopgave(r)]
```

There is no logcat output for onRestore or onCreate because it never "plays" it.
/edit

Comment: Is it crashing? What is the logcat output?

Comment: Do an edit, we cannot read code output in comments

Comment: @OliverGHjermitslev Please delete your comment; always update your question when asked for me details.

Comment: What do you mean by "closing down" the app? If you completely remove the app from the task manager, the saved instance state will also be gone. Are you implementing `Parcelable` properly? Have you debugged, what is returned exactly?

Comment: Please elaborate, because when you *close* your app, you will **not** get back your instance state. Instance state is only restored when the OS re-creates your activity after temporarily (due to memory constraints and the like) deactivating your app, not when your app is started again after being closed properly before.

Comment: In that case I have it all wrong. I guess at least I have saved my app from memory leaks.

Comment: As Blacklight said, savedInstanceState will be removed if your app is completly removed  (low memory space, user removes/stops app from manager etc). If you need for settings to persist between restarts of your app, try storing the arralist in sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

From what I read here *"... that I need to save when my users close down my app. ... but it doesn't recover it when I start the app again, either with Genymotion or physical phone."* it sounds like you are closing the app manually.

This way `onRestoreInstanceState()` won't be called. It is only called if the activity has been killed by the OS.

Check [this post](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/why-activity-ondestroy-and-activity-onrestoreinstancestate-are-not-always-called/) or [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate) as well.