# App is crashing after capturing picture using intents

Tags: android

My app is crashing after capturing 5 to 6 photos using intents.log cat shows nothing. am unable to find the reason why it is crashing. please help me out.

```
    private void capturePhoto() {

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Feedback");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME + ".jpeg");
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);


        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, requestCode);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Feedback");
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(root, Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME+".jpeg");
            checkFlowIdisPresent(file);

            displayPic();


        }
    }
  private void displayPic() {

        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/Feedback/" + Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME + ".jpeg";
        //  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        //Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 300, 300, true);


        File imgFile = new File(filePath);
        Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(imgFile);

        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            dispProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            dispProfilePic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.user_image);

        }
    }

 private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And above code is for capturing photo and displaying captured picture in ImageView. And am using MI tab.

**Edit** actually app is not crashing...it becomes white screen and if i press any button then it is crashing and onActivityResult is not executed when it become white screen

**New Edit** Am able to replicate this. I clicked on Android Monitor in that i clicked Monitor. Then it shows memory utilization of the app when i interacting with app. now in left side bar i clicked terminate application icon. Now the interesting thing is it destroys current activity and moves to previous activity. That previous activity become white screen.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: could you post the crash log? Ah log cat shows nothing..

Comment: it shows nothing. and its very hard replicate it

Comment: It has to show something. Please post it here once you do manage to replicate it, because without it, it's near impossible to help you :/

Comment: have you declared permissions in manifest file  like write external storage and camera

Comment: @NarenderReddy without permissions it would have crashed first time

Comment: ya i have added permissions

Comment: actually app is not crashing...it becomes white screen and if i press any button then it is crashing

Comment: and also i have noticed that onActivityResult is not not executed when app become white screen

Comment: Did you add singleInstance in the launchMode of the activity in manifest file?

Comment: If you did then remove that and try.

Comment: Add log to decodeFile method in catch exception block.
Cause there could be possibility that it crushing and you dont see it.

Comment: @Creotiv, Venkatesh already said the onActivityResult () is not executing

Comment: memory leaks are not out of the question, recycle all the bitmaps etc...

Comment: @JonGoodwin exactly my first thoughts. "My app is crashing after capturing 5 to 6 photos using intents" 5 to 6 HUGE photos may result in OOMException easily.

There are tools for viewing Memory allocations, objects in the memory. My advice is start from there, take the 5th picture (before the white screen) and check the memory status. There are great examples on how to deal with Bitmaps in Android. It is tricky and takes time to master, we've all been there ;)

Comment: Thanks @Lev. Now its something interesting. And thanks for giving the hint in OOMException. and let me check this first.

Comment: did you add  android:largeHeap="true"  in manifest as images need more memory

Comment: ya i have added android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. I use it in some of my apps :

Launch intent method:

```
private void launchCamera() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    }
```

Capturing result:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) {
                        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                        if (thumbnail != null)
                            displayPic(thumbnail);
                    }
                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well your code fine....

I think you save the image or overwrite image on same path with same name so there is problem with memory. So I recommended you change the name with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or any random name Instead of `Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME`.

And Also check the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Also check this permission with run time also...for run time follow [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

```
private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 123;


    if (CheckPermission(demo.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {


        capturePhoto();

    } else {
        // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
        RequestPermission(demo.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
    }



public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
                capturePhoto();

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Activity context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Constants.PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME is random flow id

Answer (score 3):

If nothing is displayed on the log cat it is very difficult to speculate anything but please check whether the problem is **when using the emulator and not on a real device.** You can also check if you can recreate the problem by making the emulator capacity smaller (Ram and internal memory). If that is the case, then increase the memory or ram of your emulator and it should work fine. You then need to work on optimizing you image processing task for lower spec devices.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This happens possibly because the **Calling Activity gets killed and then restarted** by OS as IMAGE CAPTURE intent deals with **huge amount of memory** for processing the BITMAP captured via CAMERA.

**Solution**: Save the **file path** of the Image and use it when **onActivityResult** is called. You can use **onSavedInstanceState** and **onRestoreInstanceState** methods to save and retrieve the **IMAGE_PATH** and other fields of the activity.

You can refer to this link for [how to use onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it in an Async task because the issue u facing is due to the hug processing done in UI thread

refer [here](http://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial) for more help on Async task implementation

Answer (score 2):

This may be memory problem you are taking photos and storing them in bitmap 
Check your android Monitor for Memory Detection of APp
Just make this method static

```
private static Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                    o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Save files with different names like saving with timestamp as name

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code. It works fine for me.

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
        {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos;

            try
            {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                fnfe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            ivSetImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        }
   }
}
```

In the given code snippet, I have compressed the captured image, due to which app crashing problem is resolved.

In your case, the captured image quality might be high due to which your app is crashing while setting up an image on `ImageView`.

Just try compressing an image. It will work!

Don't forget to add permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your Manifast.xml file permission 
External Storage

and Camera permission.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />    
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />  <uses-feature
> android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
> ```

if your App run on Marsh`enter code here`mallow check run time permission

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:

```
private void launchCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            if (data != null) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {
                    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    if (thumbnail != null)
                        displayPic(thumbnail);
                }
            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post links that have nothing to do with your answer!