# Activity Lifecycle when AVD is stopped in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using eclipse for Android app development. I have written both OnStop and OnDestroy methods, but when I stop the app from "Devices" tab of Eclipse, I get the message "app has died", and both the methods are not called. 
Am I missing something?

If the above behaviour is correct how to test OnStop and OnDestroy methods using AVD in eclipse?

Edit-1: Currently I am using "home" button in my computer keyboard to go to the AVD home screen to test this. Is this the best way?

My AVD does not show the home, back buttons due to some reason.

Thanks
Jagadesh S

Comment: **My AVD does not show the home, back buttons due to some reason.??** you have to check activity life cycle through "back","home " and "stop calling " buttons through emulator only..

Comment: Is using these hard buttons in AVD the only way?

Comment: answer is YES.can not operate life cycle from out side of emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnsavedInstance, it will be always called when you app destroys or stops.

Read following links for detials 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

[onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

regards
aShish

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However my question is specific on how to test these methods using AVD?