# Instance state not restoring/saving correctly

Tags: android, android-bundle

I'm attempting to save and restore a boolean field when the screen orientation changes. For whatever reason the field is saving/restoring correctly during the first orientation change, but when the orientation changes back to the initial state, the value of the boolean is wrong when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415939/1336691), I added `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the corresponding activity tag in the manifest. The following code contains the relevant methods, simplified for clarity:

```java
public class SignatureActivity extends AppCompactActivity {
    private boolean signaturePadIsEmpty = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "portrait" : "landscape";
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Orientation is " + orientation + ", signaturePadIsEmpty = " + signaturePadIsEmpty);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        signaturePadIsEmpty = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SignaturePadIsEmpty");

        String orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "portrait" : "landscape";
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: Orientation is " + orientation + ", signaturePadIsEmpty = " + signaturePadIsEmpty);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("SignaturePadIsEmpty", signaturePadIsEmpty);

        String orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? "portrait" : "landscape";
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: Orientation is " + orientation + ", signaturePadIsEmpty = " + signaturePadIsEmpty);
    }
}
```

Here's the Logcat output when I start the activity and change from portrait -> landscape and then from landscape -> portrait:

```
06-27 11:50:08.037 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onCreate: Orientation is portrait, signaturePadIsEmpty = true
06-27 11:50:12.405 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onSaveInstanceState: Orientation is landscape, signaturePadIsEmpty = false
06-27 11:50:12.461 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onCreate: Orientation is landscape, signaturePadIsEmpty = true
06-27 11:50:12.465 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onRestoreInstanceState: Orientation is landscape, signaturePadIsEmpty = false
06-27 11:50:15.068 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onSaveInstanceState: Orientation is portrait, signaturePadIsEmpty = true
06-27 11:50:15.131 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onCreate: Orientation is portrait, signaturePadIsEmpty = true
06-27 11:50:15.133 32656-32656/com.example.www.debug D/SignatureActivity: onRestoreInstanceState: Orientation is portrait, signaturePadIsEmpty = true
```

**Edit:** The problem turned out to be caused by my implementation of the signature pad's event handlers:

```java
private void initializeLayoutElements(final int orientation) {
    signaturePad = findViewById(R.id.signature_pad);
    signaturePad.setOnSignedListener(new SignaturePad.OnSignedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSigning() {
            signaturePadIsEmpty = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSigned() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onClear() {
            signaturePadIsEmpty = true;
        }
    });
}
```

The `onClear()` method was being called after `onRestoreInstanceState()` and was setting the flag to `true`. Since the solution posted by @SOreadytohelp answered my original question, I'm accepting their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple demo here on [Github](https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/SaveInstanceState) to show you how to store and restore instance state, let me know if you understand it.
It's a simple app that has a button and when you press the button you change the state of the boolean, and if you rotate the screen you still have the same value as before. I hope is what you are looking for.

They key is in `onRestoreInstanceState()` get the `Boolean` and in `onSaveInstanceState()` save the `Boolean` and you don't need this `android:configChanges="orientation` in the `manifest.xml`

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    signaturePadIsEmpty = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("SignaturePadIsEmpty");
    tvState.setText(String.valueOf(signaturePadIsEmpty));

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("SignaturePadIsEmpty", signaturePadIsEmpty);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The relevant lines of code in your snippet are identical to the snippet in my question, so I'm not sure what I should be doing differently.

Comment: I mean, if you don't add the thing of your `manifest.xml` on my demo it works perfect, even if I copy your code...

Comment: I found the issue. Looks like the signature pad's `onClear()` event handler was being called after restoring the state. I set the flag `signaturePadIsEmpty` to `true` in this handler. 

Comment: Sorry, should have included that part of the code. I assumed the bug was related to how I was saving/restoring the instance state.