# onSaveInstanceState for ImageVeiw

Tags: java, android

I'm making a dice game and I want to save the image View when I rotate the screen.

I have tried to save the value and then re-establish it. This worked but when I wanted to download the picture but the value I saved it does not work.

```
// How do I save this?

public void setDiceOne() {
    getDiceOne = new DiceAll(diceOne);
    getDiceOne.getRandomNumber();
    getDiceOne.getImageWhite();
}

public void setDiceTwo() {
    getDiceTwo = new DiceAll(diceTwo);
    getDiceTwo.getRandomNumber();
    getDiceTwo.getImageWhite();
}
```

Comment: Improve your explanation.

Comment: I want to be able to save the values onSaveInstanceState and when the screen turns, everything is reset. so i want to resume my value from
  if (savedInstanceState! = null) from the onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) method
I don't know how to do it. I have been sitting with this for three days, I do not know if I have to do if the whole program takes too much time.

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101501/9968399).

Comment: not really what I'm looking for. I do not want to send data to another activity. The data I want to save is in the same activity.
I can kind of do that
getDiceOne = new DiceAll (diceOne);
oneVal = getDiceOne.getRandomNumber ();
getDiceOne.getImageWhite (oneVal);

here i can save the dice value and then submit it and get the image getDiceOne.getImageWhite (oneVal);
i can save oneVal in onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
outState.putInt (VALONE, oneVal);
and then resume from onCreate ()
  if (savedInstanceState! = null) {
oneVal = savedInstanceState.getInt (VALONE);

Comment: then my problem is how I pass it into
     @Override
     protected void onResume () {
         super.onResume ();
getDiceOne.getImageWhite (oneVal);
 }
so this does not work. I don't really know what to do

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your problem correctly. Edit your question and include the code that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I've solved the problem