# Using of onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

I have an activity and when I am pressing home button I have the next activity lifecycle:

```
   D/States: Login: onPause()
   D/States: Login: onStop()
   D/States: onSaveInstanceState
   D/States: Login: onDestroy()
```

When I again entering my application, I have:

```
D/States: Login: onStart()
D/States: Login: onResume()
D/States: Login: onPause()
D/States: Login: onResume()
```

But `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is not called and activity state is not saved.

**Overrides:**

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "Login: onStart()");
    }

    @Override

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "Login: onResume()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "Login: onPause()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "Login: onStop()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Login: onDestroy()");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("login", mEmailView.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("password", mPasswordView.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mEmailView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("login"));
        mPasswordView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("password"));
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");

    }
```

As I know, `onRestoreInstanceState()` method should be called in `onResume()` or `onStart()`.

I read about `configChanges` somewhere in Google while searching answer on my question. I have not `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` or some else `android:configChanges` in my manifest.

**But why it is not called in my activity?**
Solved.

Comment: You might have added configChanges to your AndroidManifest. Please paste the manifest snippet here

Comment: I read about this somewhere in Google while searching answer on my question. I have not `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` or some else `android:configChanges` in my manifest.

Comment: why did you comment out super.onSaveINstanceState(outState)?

Looks like you save no state since call to super occurs before string storage

Comment: The bundle that was saved in onSaveInstanceState is available in onCreate

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Comment: @MaksimTuraev I have tried both variants of calling `super.` in this method

Comment: @AbhishekNandi you are talking about restoring state in `onCreate()` method? Like         `if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mEmailView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("login"));
            mPasswordView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("password"));
        }`? If yes - it is not working.

Comment: Generally you would use `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in place of `onRestoreInstanceState` for sake of reliability.

Comment: And there is an anomaly in log D/States: Login: onStart()
D/States: Login: onResume()
D/States: Login: onPause()
D/States: Login: onResume(), some strange onPause onResume calls. And you should also log oncreate. 

Github sample would be even better

Comment: It is not normal that your `Login` `Activity` is being destroyed when the user presses the HOME button. Please post your manifest, and the code that starts `Login` (if this isn't the root `Activity`) as that may help to explain why it is being destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a duplicate...

Ok.

Earlier I was in need to destroy some other activity by any way when the app is minimized.
So I used `android:noHistory`.

And of course I have created "Login" activity with copy-paste and forgot to delete `noHistory`.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentations:

> **This method is called after onStart() when the activity is being
>   re-initialized from a previously saved state**, given here in
>   savedInstanceState. Most implementations will simply use
>   onCreate(Bundle) to restore their state, but it is sometimes
>   convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done
>   or to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default
>   implementation. The default implementation of this method performs a
>   restore of any view state that had previously been frozen by
>   onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)

Activity is re-initialized either after orientation change or being recreated after being killed by OS due to memory limitation.

In your  case by pressing home button the activity just goes to to stopped state, unless your phone is running low on resources like memory, then get killed by OS, in that case `onRestoreInstanceState()` will be called

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand how this should help to call minimized activity in state, which was saved in `onSaveInstanceState` method

Answer (score 0):

When you press the home button, your activity is not destroyed or recreated. When you bring it back from recent apps, the activity starts and will not be recreated unless it was killed by OS to reclaim memory if the memory was low. It is behaving as expected

Comment: If you read the question, it is clear that the `Login` `Activity` is being destroyed.